# How can I preserve my icon size in Illustrator on export?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, cs6, png, pixel

I have created a few icons of `64px x 64px` on one canvas in Illustrator CS6. Now I need each of the icons to be in `.png` file format. So I created a new document in Illustrator with `64px x 64px` dimensions and copy paste one of the previously created icons. Now when I want to save it as f `.png` file format it does not remain `64px x 64px` size rather it becomes like `63px x 63px` size with 1 pixel from 2 sides erased. What mistake did I make and what is the remedy to it? How do I get to a `64px x 64px` size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly you need to make sure to have `Use Artboards`:

`File -> Export -> Use Artboards`

[image]

This was also on Stacked awhile ago: "[Keep original size when export image from illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396247/keep-original-size-when-export-image-from-illustrator)"

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:

Select an artboard and press "shift+O". Check artbard properties in the top right hand side. X postion(X), Y position(Y), Height(H) and width(W) all should be integers. **NO DECIMAL VALUES**. Now, there won't be even a pixel change while exporting.

Comment: Hi prasad, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!